# Generic interface in java with WildCard

Tags: java, generics, types, type-conversion

I am bit confused mixing Java generics interfaces and type wildcard. 
I am trying to implement a generic way to pass  a list of options to a method where the type of the option is unknown at compile type.

I did in the following way, but I get an error at compile time.

Generic Interface :

```
public interface IOption<T> { 
    public T getOption();
}
```

This method should take in input a list of options of unknown type, so I used a wild card.

```
public interface IAction {
    boolean do(Iterable<IOption<?>> options);
}
```

The I created the following list of boolean options :

```
    IOption<Boolean> option =  new IOption<Boolean>(){
            @Override
            public Boolean getOption() {
                return new Boolean(doEnable);
            }           
        };
    Iterable<IProjectStateOption<Boolean>> options = 
                   Collections.singletonList(option);
```

but when the method `do` is called I get the following error :

```
The method do( Iterable<IOption<?>>) in the type IAction is not applicable for 
the arguments (Iterable<IOption<Boolean>>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `Iterable<Option<Boolean>>` cannot be converted to an `Iterable<Option<?>>`, even though `Option<Boolean>` is convertible to `Option<?>`.

You want `Iterable<? extends Option<?>>`.

Comment: yes, you are right. Can you explain a bit further why I can't do that conversion?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to change your do method or your specific iterator since `Iterable<IProjectStateOption>` is not valid for `Iterable<IOption>`.

```
public interface IAction {
   boolean do(Iterable<? extends IOption> options);
}
```

If you want to specify the specific type of `IOption` then you need to to use `<T>` in `IAction` as well

```
public interface IAction<T>
```